# How to access the name variable in my html object with react

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to access the name of the variable in my html with this

```
  const changeCurrentType = (e) => {
    setCurrentType(e.target);
    console.log(e.target)
  }
```

The function is able to print this with e.target
[image]

How however, when I write

```
console.log(e.target.name)
```

It prints undefined. May I know how can I access the name variable of div? In my case, how can I get the "subclub" from name="subclub"?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using name attribute instead of data-set attributes on DOM elements other than input ?

Comment: also, `<div>` elements do not support the `value` & `name` attributes.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to figure this out by using the getAttribute('name') method.

Comment: that doesn't mean it is correct. If you want to use non-standard attributes, you should use `data-` custom attributes as @SanuKhan suggested. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

Comment: Oh that does make a lot of sense, thank you @RandyCasburn and SanuKhan, I will look into ur suggestions and implement them in my future projects and refactor my code. sorry new to web dev so i dont know a lot about best practices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the question with this line of code to access the div

```
  const changeCurrentType = (e) => {
    setCurrentType(e.target.getAttribute('name'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-name="name"></div>

const changeCurrentType = (e) => {
setCurrentType(e.target.dataset); // {name: "name"} }
```